# Use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay for animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkoverlay

is it a good idea to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay for animation purpose when **UIView or CALayers are just not available**?

More specifically I am working with MKOverlayRenderer which can display something like an UIView does. I'd like to animate a movement of this `MKOverlayRenderer` (just think of a progress bar). In my implementation I just repeatedly send `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` to **update the position** of the MKOverlayRenderer in very short time intervals.

It works quite well but I am concerned about the performance since the CPU usage rises from ~0% to 15% (if I set the delay to 0.5 seconds) and 90% (delay = 0.02).

Are there are any other options or can I just ignore the CPU peaks?

Comment: CPU usage would be from the code you are calling, not the use of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of anything specifically for MKOverlayRenderer, but you can create an NSTimer like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *myTimer;
```

And then instantiate it:

```
self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(myMethod)
                                              userinfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
```

and then your method:

```
- (void)myMethod {
    //do whatever MKOverlayRenderer animation you need
}
```

and then to stop the timer:

```
[self.myTimer invalidate];
self.myTimer = nil;
```

But just remember that the CPU overload is from the animation you're running, not the timer.